# How to creae GIT Local Repo having different structure to GIT Server Repo

Tags: eclipse, git, github

The reason for such requirement is We are using a Proprietary product which only supports a specific structure in Eclipse Project within a custom Eclipse perspective also provided by the plugin.

Now To have meaningful segregation of files for readability, Our team wants specific folders to consist certain files.

Those folders to be checked in only ( not the Eclipse Project created by proprietary plugin)

Now say my Eclipse project folder is :

```
    Proj
      |__Folder1
              |__file1    
              |__file2
              |__Folder2
                    |__file3
```

And I want to store:

```
     git
      |__Different_Folder_Name_Folder1
      |       |__file2    
      |
      |__Different_Folder_Name_Folder2
              |__Different_file_name_file1
              |__Different_file_name_file3
```

Questions:

1. Should I store the wished structure in Local Repo or GIT server Repo?
2. Based on previous answer, how to

   ```
       a. create and maintain these separate structure? and 
       b. keep sync between these separate structures?(clone/pull/fetch/commit/push)
   ```

Note: I'm almost novice at GIT. So spare me from down vote on this query.
      I am also not asking how to switch between dev / prod in same folder.
      If this approach is wrong then suggestions are welcome too

Comment: Not really a solution but as Git is kind of "dumb" system and assumes what you have on disk is what you actually want, you could probably do this by creating a staging repository which uses symlinks to put the files where you want them to appear in the external repo. This would be amazingly brittle though and probably would break all the time, so I very heavily doubt there's a good solution for this.

Comment: @Esko 
thnx a ton:)...Waiting for any detailed way out for the same ...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible.

Even if one solution is existing for your wish, it isn't best practice.